# Does Vecna need to kill according to a pattern, or does he choose to?

Tags: stranger-things

In Season 4 of *Stranger Things*, there is an entity known as "Vecna" that targets and kills people, seemingly only people who have experienced some unresolved trauma, whom he

> haunts in daydreams before brutally killing them to open small portals between the Upside-Down and Earth.

Of course, in reality Vecna is:

> Henry a.k.a. One a.k.a. the Mind Flayer?

It seems as if there are two possibilities here:

- Vecna can only kill victims who have some sort of trauma that he can use to gain access to their mind. In support of this idea: precisely the fact that despite the importance of his plan, he targets precisely those people and takes his time killing them.
- Vecna can attack anyone he wants at any time, but he chooses people who are tormented and tortures them over time because he is sadistic. In support of this idea: Vecna's powers are similar to Eleven's, and she can see people without such requirements; Vecna was able to see and attack Nancy immediately (but he did attack her within the Upside-Down).

Which of these is the case? Or is there something else at play?